# Are all Traditional Yorkies black and gold?

Tags: dogs, terminology

Are all Traditional Yorkies black and gold colored?

Can a "Traditional Yorkie" (Yorkshire Terrier), be any color but Black and Gold? When ones says "traditional" are they always referring to Black and Gold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yorkshire Terriers are born black and tan and their coat changes colors to a dark steel blue and tan gradually as they mature. The tan in the headfall should be a rich golden tan. The tan color should not extend down the back of the neck.

For more information, you can read the full breed standards.

[UKC Breed Standard](http://www.ukcdogs.com/Web.nsf/Breeds/CompanionDog/YorkshireTerrier03012008)

[AKC Breed Standard](https://www.akc.org/breeds/yorkshire_terrier/breed_standard.cfm)

[The Kennel Club Breed Standard](http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/services/public/breed/standard.aspx?id=6165)